# android libgdx bind 6 diffrent texture to cube

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing game for Android in which I have to draw cube with different texture at each face.

I am using libgdx game development framework to develop this game.

My code to draw cube is as follow :

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) 
{
    Mesh cube_mesh  =   ModelLoaderOld.loadObj(Gdx.files.internal("data/cube.obj").read());
    cube_mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);}
```

Now I want to bind 6 different texture to this cube. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider creating your cube in code rather then loading it from an obj file. This will allow you to completely customise the generating of texture coordinates, which you will most likely need to create an efficient solution.

Instead of using 6 textures you'd just use one texture but specify a different set of coordinates for each face. Each texture coordinate will then point to a location on your texture atlas. This way you could even have multiple cube textures in one big texture atlas. It'll be much more efficient this way since it'll minimise texture switches.

For a cube with each face having it's own set of texture coordinates you will need 4 vertices per face with 6 indices per face. So a total of 24 vertices and 36 indices.

Comment: There are many tutorials up there, might I suggest you look into http://blog.xoppa.com/